# Azure DevOps PowerShell task fails to load 'Az.CosmosDB' module

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, pipeline, powershell-module

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline to rotate Cosmos DB account keys. To do this, I'm using PowerShell and the `New-AzCosmosDBAccountKey` cmdlet.

For some unknown reason, the `Az.CosmosDB` module is not installed with `Az`, so it needs to be installed manually each time the pipeline is run.

`Install-Module -Name Az.CosmosDb -AllowClobber -Force`

When I run this locally everything works as expected, but within Azure DevOps I see an error

> The 'Get-AzCosmosDBAccountKey' command was found in the module 'Az.CosmosDB', but the module could not be loaded.

What might be happening in Azure DevOps that differs from what is happening locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is that an update was made to the `Az.CosmosDb` module so that it specifically requires version 1.9.4 (or higher) of `Az.Accounts`. However, on the Azure DevOps hosted agent they use version 1.9.3.

To fix, I changed the command that manually installs the `Az.CosmosDb` module -

```
Install-Module -Name Az.CosmosDb -RequiredVersion 0.1.6 -AllowClobber -Force
```

#### Note

When I found on the PowerShell Gallery that all versions of the `Az.CosmosDb` module were < **1.0.0** I did some investigation and it turns out that the module is still in preview, despite Cosmos DB having existed for years. This explains why the module is not installed along side all other `Az.*` modules when installing `Az`.

What is very frustrating is that there is no mention anywhere on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cosmosdb/?view=azps-4.7.0#cosmos-db) for the module that it is in preview. If there were, it would probably have saved me a good chunk of time!

Answer (score 0):

Please check when you run DevOps Pipeline, which agent pool you are using. If you use microsoft-hosted agent, each time you run a pipeline, you get a fresh virtual machine. The virtual machine is discarded after one use. So you need to install the `Az.CosmosDB` module manually each time.

You could also deploy an agent on your local machine, in this way, it's supposed not need to nstall the `Az.CosmosDB` module manually each time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser

Comment: I'm using a hosted agent, hence why I am installing the module on each run. From reading the error message, the issue seems not to be that the module isn't installed, but that the hosted agent is not able to read the module.

Comment: Do you also get this error when you installed the module manually?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole problem - I am installing the module manually because it's not installed along with `Az` so isn't initially available on the hosted agent. To install manually I'm using `Install-Module -Name Az.CosmosDb -AllowClobber -Force`. There is no error and the module seems to install, but as soon as I try to use a cmdlet from the module PowerShell throws the error as described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems today Azure DevOps finally broke everything, old variant with

```
Install-Module Az.CosmosDB -RequiredVersion 0.1.6 -Force
```

has stopped working. Amazing, the whole experience with Az DevOps and Azure technologies are pretty the same, each time they just suddenly have stopped working at random places!

UPD: The gallery source address is dead https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.CosmosDB/0.1.6 , looks that is the reason

Comment: ps gallery status is here https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGallery/blob/master/psgallery_status.md#powershell-gallery-status